# Python Script for creating a GUI using opencv

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, opencv3.0

So,I have written this opencv-python code for real time image processing using haar cascades and features like ORB.I have also created a simple gui in python with a button.But on clicking this button i want to run the other python script which has the image processing part.How to do this?
I am using ubuntu.

Comment: Seems to be the easy part after what you'Ve already done. Take a look at how other tools use TkInter for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First,

```
   import tkFileDialog
```

then,

```
wid=Tk()
wid1=Button(None,text="hello guys",command=hello) #ur function hello
wid2=Button(None,text="Quit",command=quitbtn) #ur function quitbtn
wid3=Button(None,text="upload it",command=my)  #ur function my
wid1.grid(row=0,column=0)
wid2.grid(row=0,column=1)
wid3.grid(row=0,column=2)

wid.mainloop()
```

Kinda a crude way,but works for small applications.

Comment: u need to have Tkinter,
Open terminal and type:sudo apt-get install python-tk